# Excel Rank Multiple Columns

Tags: excel

I'm facing a issue with ranking in Excel particularly in regards to tie breaking. I tried several options but i guess they don't fit my issue. Its quite simple really, I'll explain:

The Data:

```
1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10


87  83  74  95  69  90  73  0   74  85
121 121 96  121 121 121 121 83  121 121
```

As you can see its easy for me to rank the first line (I'm working in columns instead of rows for the data). When i do a Rank Function gives the following result:

```
3   5   6   1   9   2   8   10  6   4
```

Which is correct.
The problem arises in the second line. There are ties because all of them reach the maximum of 121:

```
1   1   9   1   1   1   1   10  1   1
```

What i would like to do is take the first row as a tie breaker. So even if there is a tie the first line which was firstly text but now is a sequence from 1 to 10 could provide as secondary criteria to order the rank, thus giving the following ranking line:

```
1   2   9   3   4   5   6   10  7   9
```

Could one achieve this result?

Thank You very much in advance.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Just [Googling](https://www.google.nl/search?q=excel+rank+with+tie+breaker) gives many results/ideas, such as [this page](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/448361-unique-rank-tie-breaker.html). What has/hasn't worked?

Comment: Hello, Yes i did try it but it didn't work. I think I tried most of the CountIF and SumProduct formulas out there. Im trying too think of a way of doing a Index Match but its not giving the desired output. Thank you

Comment: What index/match formula are you using?

Comment: I used =Index(the range of line 1(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10)); Match(121, range of 121); exact match. i was guessing i could get the number in line 1 in case if it was 1 which it did by adding a IF condition but it got me the raw score if it was 1. I looked further in the internet and still couldn't find something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a helper row to break the tie. You can add a fraction of the first row to the second row to create a new row & use the new row to rank

[image]

```
A4 = A3+(A2/(MAX($A$2:$J$2)+1))
```

Using the MAX I ensure the fraction is less than 1 which is adequate to break ties in this case.

```
A6 = RANK(A4,$A$4:$J$4)
```

You can hide the helper row if you dont want to show it.